# Akeeba Backup vs. Akeeba Kickstart

Tags: joomla-3.x, akeebabackup

They both perform the same task of backing up a website ( or just files essentially ). Are there any important considerations that would suggest it is better to use the [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html) extension or just the [Akeeba Kickstart](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html)? The respective product information pages show they would both do, at a high level, the same thing.

I just intend to zip the website ( and database ) to file so that I can keep a copy. If either of these utilities would do then that would be the answer. Looks like they have different features like Backup supports cloud backup. At the core are they still the same? I have seen both recommended here.

Primarily I'm not seeking opinions but facts that might drive the decision one way or the other.

Comment: yeah... sorry for wasting peoples time with this one. Hopefully this will help others.

Comment: Don't worry about it, it can be a bit confusing at first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Akeeba backup is used to `create backups` of your site. You can create backups as ZIP, JPA or JPS files. This means you can make a copy of your site-articles, configurations, database etc and store it in one convenient file.

Akeeba Kickstart is used to `**restore** the backup file` you created using Akeeba backup. By restore I mean you use the backup file to recreate your website. You don't have to use Akeeba Kickstart to restore- it is just one method of restoring your backup file.

Comment: I just feel stupid now. Thanks for the answer. You last answer using bold was better than the code formatting FWIW.

Answer (score 4):

No. **They are not the same.**

*Akeeba Backup* is the main extension to create a backups.

When you restore a backup, you have to copy *Akeeba Kickstart* script and the backuped file to restore the whole site.

Comment: I just feel stupid now. Thanks for the clarification. Another case of not reading and assuming. I guess i just found the name misleading _Kickstarter_ misleading _at first_.